# Having multiple URL rewriting in one backend in HAProxy

Tags: java, linux, haproxy, high-availability

I have to implement a scenario where we will be having only one backend with 3 servers. 
Out of 3, for 2 servers will accept different URL pattern.
So we are using "reqirep"  to replace the string in incoming request and change it to the pattern acceptable by server 1&2.And Server3 accepts only the original incoming request pattern. 
Now, the problem is that once the request comes it's been replaced by pattern given in "reqirep" so server3 is not accepting the request. How to have "reqirep" apply only to server1&2 and original request apply to server3 inside single backend in haproxy?

Comment: I guess  do not understand your problem, use reqirep in each section backend?

Comment: it was not a question.

Comment: Let me try to explain. Based on the ACL appropriate backend will be selected.
 backend ABC 
   #replace string in request URL with "aaa" and forward to server1&2
     reqirep  ^(.*)/somestring             \1/aaa\2
     server     server1
     server      server2
   #use original request URL without any replace
     server      server3

Problem is the new URL is trying to hit server3. Since server3 will not accept new pattern it fails.
New URL should be applied only to server1&2.
How to achieve this?
Can we have seperate "reqirep" for each server in same backend?